# README.md file missing on github

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I put my local repository on github. In the github repository, I created README file by clicking the "we recommend a README file link". I wrote a detailed content in it and committed it. But I did not clone this file into my local repository. Recently, I made some changes and pushed them to the github repo. Today I noticed that the README file is missing. I checked my commits and couldn't find anything related to README there.

I am using Eclipse egit plugin to interact with the github repository. I did click on "synchronize workspace" in Eclipse "Team" menu, just to check what it does - this is before I noticed that the file is missing.

Is there anyway to retrieve my README.md file? Please let me know.

My repository: https://github.com/raghavam/d-sparq

Comment: No README (or readme) file is present in any of the 20 commits in that repository.

Comment: @Messa, Yes thats the point. I created and updated README online, using the browser, following the recommended "adding a README" link provided. Won't this be logged as a commit? I don't see it either. But I am very sure of creating a detailed README file and updating it several times.

Comment: I don't know about EGit works, but it sounds like it might have overridden any commits on your remote, possibly with a force push. If at any point in time you had done a fetch or pull from your remote before you did the synchronize thing, it's possible that the readme is still sitting in your local repo in a dangling commit somewhere. You could possibly find it by searching `git reflog`.

Comment: @Cupcake, Yes, I did tick an option called "force push" in Egit because without that it was giving me an error. What does a force push do when compared to a regular push? But, I haven't done a fetch or pull - I don't generally do that because I am the only one using that repo and so my current local copy would be the latest. ''git reflog'' prints all the commit IDs and messages. I checked the commits on the github repo page.

Comment: @Cupcake, previous message was incomplete, sorry. I checked the commits on the github repo page but I don't find README in them. If I update and save the changes on the repo page itself (using browser), isn't it same as commit? Why doesn't it show that log?

Comment: @Raghava you edited and committed from a link [like this](https://github.com/coldhawaiian/test/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @Cupcake, Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229904/readme-md-file-missing-on-github?noredirect=1#comment35552042_23229904), the original poster says:

> Yes, I did tick an option called "force push" in Egit because without that it
>   was giving me an error. What does a force push do when compared to a regular
>   push?
>
> But, I haven't done a fetch or pull - I don't generally do that because I am
>   the only one using that repo and so my current local copy would be the latest.

Yeah, it definitely sounds like you ended up force-pushing your local copy of
your repo, which then overwrote the changes you made to your README file on
GitHub, especially since you say that you never fetch or pull.

The problem with never fetching or pulling is that you describe editing and
committing a README file through GitHub's web interface:

> I created README file by clicking the "we recommend a README file link". I
>   wrote a detailed content in it and committed it. But I did not clone this file
>   into my local repository.

So your remote repo has commits that your local repo doesn't. That's probably
the error message you were getting when you tried to push, something along these
lines, right?:

```
git push origin master
# To https://github.com/user/repo.git
#  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/repo.git'
```

That message basically means that you need to [merge the remote commits with the
work in your local repository](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors). But instead of doing that, you just
completely overwrote those commits to the README file (that you did remotely) by
using force-push, which you should not have done if you didn't really understand
what it does.

Be very, very careful with force-push. Only use it when you understand what it
does and you're sure that using it is what you want to do, because it's one of
the most common ways for Git beginners to end up losing work.

### Recovering the README

Since you never fetched or pulled from your repository, the file is basically
unrecoverable now, because it was never downloaded to your local remote. You'll
need to start over.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you. I learnt it the hard way. I will rewrite the README.

Comment: @Raghava it's OK, we all make mistakes. Just be glad that it was just a README file instead of something more important.

Comment: yes, that was the error that I got, which I should have looked into instead of taking the easier option. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It is not unrecoverable, there is a chance it exists on remote repository `reflog`. Normally you can't access remote repository reflog but github has events API.

```
# show the events on repo (including commits)
curl -u <username> https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/events

# create a new branch from the commit sha found in prev command
curl -i -u <username> -X POST -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/new-branch", "sha":"<lost-sha>"}' 
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs
```

The first command lets you find the sha of lost remote commit.
The second command lets you create a branch on that commit.
Then simply fetch all changes on local repo and new branch should appear.
After that simply merge that branch or cherry-pick the commit and push.

Comment: This just saved me so much time

Comment: I couldn't get the second part of this "creating the new branch" to work, but once I had the lost SHA from the first step it was easy enough to visit github.com/<owner>/<repo>/commit/<lost-sha> to view that specific commit which contained the entire README I had lost.

Comment: @GeoffreyH You are an absolute legend!